# Daily Vote Limit Reached at 38 Votes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting

I've voted 38 times today and can't up/down-vote any questions or answers, getting the Daily Vote Limit Reached message.

Does flagging a comment as Spam count against these? Or any other actions?

Edit: Just notice I downvoted twice today, might that affect the count?
Edit 2: Holocryptic has also reached the "Daily Vote Limit" message, his user page reports 33 votes.

Comment: It's a little ironic (more so than rain on your wedding day; that's just unfortunate).  They want us to vote more, but put caps on how often you can vote.

Comment: I'll say that I got capped today at 33, allegedly.

Comment: I think I got capped at 38 yesterday and today it is 36.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see:

[Please don't require answer votes to be cast before question votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes/90256#90256)

For each Q Vote before you use your first 30 votes, you get an extra vote. You voted on 8 Questions before hitting 30, so you got a total of 38 votes. Once you've hit 30, the extra votes earned before 30 are fixed (if you're 31+ votes are for Qs you can not earn any more 'extra votes').

Answer (score 1):

I started this as a comment, but

That answer by waffles on meta.SO ins't very clear, here's the best I can figure out from the other answers and Sam's answer here about "if 1 of 3...":

- You get 30 votes for sure.
- You might get 10 more votes, depending on how many of your first 30 votes are on questions.
- This next part is a bit hazy, hasn't been answered clearly.  It looks like if you cast 10 question votes before you get to 25 total votes, you'll get the extra 10 votes.  Or maybe, based on Sam's answer, if you get to 30 votes and at all times have cast 33% of your votes on questions, you'll get the extra 10.
- If you're close, but slightly under that 1 in 3 ratio, you might get less than 10 bonus votes.  Once the system has decided you've got only 5 votes left, you can't "earn" any more bonus votes by voting on questions.

Arg, whatever, it's apparently too complicated to summarize based on incomplete information.  We all get between 30 and 40 votes depending on how many of the first 30 are on questions.  Good enough.

I guess that means the new badge stays in place, too.

**Note:** That "SE New Features" page/question on meta.SO hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: It would appear that you only get the new badge if you cast all 40 votes. @Holocryptic gat a suffrage badge for casting 33 votes which was all he was allowed to cast.

Comment: I'm glad doing sys admin stuff isn't as complicated as this voting crap.

Comment: it was originally that you got 30 votes, then 10 more for questions only. People complained so Waffles tried to make it so that if you had 10 Q Votes you could cast 30 A Votes. Apparently this is not working correctly however and thus you end up with the situation you summarized: 30 to 40 depending on how you voted in the first 30.